# How to sove Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: orders.forEach is not a function ? Vue.JS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My mutations in module vuex store is like this :

```
const mutations = {
    [types.GET_STATUS] (state,{ orders }) {
        console.log(orders)
        state.status = {}
        orders.forEach(message => {
            set(state.status, message.id, message)
        })
    },
}
```

The result of `console.log(orders)` is like this :

> Object {1: "status 1", 2: "status 2", 3: "status 3"}

When it executed, there exist error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: orders.forEach is not a function

How can I solve it?

Comment: Just, `state.status = orders`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't iterate over an object with `forEach`. `forEach` is an array method. If you wanted to, you could grab the keys and iterate over them.

```
const keys = Object.keys(orders);
keys.forEach(key => set(state.status, key, orders[key])
```

But in this case, wouldn't just

```
set(state, status, orders)
```

work? I'm assuming `set` is available in this context. Or even possibly just

```
state.status = orders
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was only this : `state.status = orders`